# taskset and unknown thread on linux

Tags: linux, multithreading, pthreads

My company has just brought a software API that spawns off a monitoring thread (when enabled).  This monitoring thread is very useful however we would like to lock it to core 0 in Linux. However, I can't use taskset in the normal fashion IE

```
# taskset -c 2,3 12345
```

because I don't know the PID of the monitoring thread. I have asked the vendor if it is possible to get the PID of the thread outputted to a log file or similar and they said "we will look into that" which means no.

So my question is how do you find the PID of this monitoring thread from outside so I can taskset it?

Comment: Why do you want to lock the thread to core 0? What are your specific reasons to not trust the kernel scheduler? And the thread does not have a unique pid, but a unique tid, (see the Linux specific [gettid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/gettid.2.html) syscall)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at numactl from libnuma. It looks like you can use that to set a core affinity policy and have it launch your program for you with that policy already in force.

I've not read the manpage in detail, but I suspect that the launched program is at liberty to override that policy by making the relevant system calls if it was written to do so in the first place. But I'd imagine that unless the program makes no such decisions for itself then you can restrict the whole process to any core you like.

So perhaps you can run your program under numactl restricted to core 0. Then when the third party library has started its thread (presumably you're calling some sort of library initialise routine that itself spawns the monitor thread) you could make your own system calls to relax the core affinity policy inherited from numactl.

However I agree with Basile Starynkevitch - you have to have some very particular circumstances before messing around with core affinity is worthwhile. In my experience you only gain something if the program has lots of threads that are really hammering the memory system and if you also address the problem of memory affinity (that's something else you can do with libnuma). Intel and AMD's hardware is really very good, and you'll have to work really hard to improve on the Linux scheduler's decisions.

You may also like to consider the PREEMPT_RT kernel patch, which you can get pre-packed with Redhat MRG or CERNs Scientific Linux. It does a good job of making scheduling in Linux more consistent in terms of maximum and average context switch times. I suggest it because although you've not said as such I sense that what you really want is for some other thread to be scheduled more reliably, more consistently. PREEMPT_RT does a good job of that.